# Discord.py bot replies itself(it detects its own messages)

Tags: python, discord.py

````
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    content = message.content
    author = message.author
    print("{}: {}".format(author, content))
    if message.content.startswith(".play"):
        pass
    elif message.content.startswith(".echo"):
        content = message.content
        #
        """
        msg = message.content.split()
        await message.delete()
        output = ""
        for word in msg[1:]:
            output += word
            output += " "
        if "gay" in output:
            await message.channel.send("Only the gay person is godlessarp")
        else:
            await message.channel.send(output)
        #
        """
        import random as r
        words = ["..."]

        word = r.choice(words)
        user_input = ""
        i = 0
        guesses = 8
        hint = ""
        for i in range(7):
            await message.channel.send("Guess the word!")
            user_input = content
            if guesses > 0:
                if user_input == word:
                    await message.channel.send("YOU FOUND THE WORD!")
                    break
                elif user_input != word:
                    try:
                        await message.channel.send("Incorrect!")
                        hint += word[i]
                        await message.channel.send("Here is the hint: " + hint)
                        i += 1
                        guesses -= 1
                        user_input = ""
                        print(i)
                        print(guesses)
                    except:
                        await message.channel.send("Game Over!")
            elif guesses == 0:
                await message.channel.send("Game Over!")
    elif "<@!753572933594775663>" in content:
        await message.channel.send("```If you need help please mail ariyurektuna@gmail.com```")
        await message.channel.send("```Or you can Dm the high rank members!```")

    elif message.content == ".play":
        pass
````

When I write .echo it literally plays the game itself(it answers itself)I tried to reset the content at the start of the loop but it did not work.Also it sometimes stops??.Another problem is that i tried to put this game code on .play clause but when I type in the chat it doesn't respond, it doesn't give a error. So I commented .echo code and replaced it with game code. Now it works but still same loop...I couldn't find a way to prevent this please help!

Comment: The only problem is, is the bot playing by itself?

Comment: yeah it replies it self "it detects itself"

Comment: There is no tutorial or info for that @Nurqm

Comment: @TunaAriyurek You could simply check if the author of the incoming message is itself! Something like `if message.author == client.user: return`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want bot to reply itself, you should add

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot:
        return
```

this, so if message author is a bot, it will ignore the message.